# How to add link for specific word in text via JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, hyperlink, dynamic-linking

I´m looking for solution how to add a link for specific word in text via PHP or JS.

*For example:*

I would like to **add link** for each word "**lorem**" in the text automatically.

like this: `<a href=https://wwww.google.com/>lorem</a>`

"**[Lorem](http://google.com)** ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim **[lorem](http://google.com)** ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut  aliquip etc."

Any suggestions?

Thaks a lot for any answers.

Comment: Via PHP? In what context?

Comment: Just `str_replace()` in PHP or `replace()` in JS?

Comment: Well, I need add link for each specific word. See the example "lorem". Each word "lorem" in text is linked to google. I don´t know if PHP is the right way how to do it automatically.

Comment: use regex with replace

Comment: I´m happy for all of yours answers but I would like to say that I´ m not really good in PHP or JS so if you will briefly write some solid code I will be happy for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this would work but you can give it a try.

```
$search = 'lorem';
$replace = '<a href="mypage.php">lorem</a>';

$str = "my text";

echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$str);
```

Comment: Looks like a start..

Comment: Yes that good but is there any way how to do it withouth adding text into $str="my text"? Like search lorem in whole big webpage? In my case this is not the best way how to do it.

Comment: @rudi You can just put your web page in the $str and it will work i think.

Answer (score 1):

If you use javascript, you have to split the `string` and loop through each and compare if equals to something `lorem` and assign a new value `the link here`

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim lorem ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip etc";

split = text.split(' ');

//assign a new value 
split[i] = (split[i] === 'Lorem' || split[i] === 'lorem') ? '<a href=https://wwww.google.com/>lorem</a>': split[i];
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nesmar/1g964p4n/)

Note: This might not satisfy your problem but can give you an idea on how to do it.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, but this is pretty same like comment before. Big problem is that the text can not be in any var or $something="text". I guess the best way how to do it is to read a "div" which includes the text and search for the word in the div without adding the text anywere. But Im not sure if is that possible to do it in this way.

Comment: Yes its possible, just select the element containing that text `var text = $('your wrap element').html();`